# When uniQuery is opened, why DataSource.onDataChange trigger 2 times?

Tags: delphi, ado, unidac

I've a question about unidac's `uniQuery`:

when `uniQuery` open, if a `DataSource` component is linked, the   `DataSource.onDataChange` will trigger 2 times, and `ADOQuery` trigger just 1 time, why?

Environment:

1. uniDAC：6.4, 7;
2. delphi: 7, xe 10.1 berlin

Comment: environment:
1 uniDAC：6.4, 7;
2 delphi: 7, xe 10.1 berlin

Comment: If you want to add details to your question, do so by editing the question (see the `edit` button below the tags)

Comment: How many records (returned from uniQuery) do you have?

Comment: i'v already tested 2 kind of table:
1. only 1 record 
2. more than 10 thousands records 
and different "uniQuery.fetchrows" 

no different

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg:  i see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem many times, I found that it is a default loading behavior not just in the Uni-component, all similar database components will trigger `.onDataChange` twice or more when loading, the only way to go over it is by using workarounds to ignore the 1st trigger.

You can find also a similar problem [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B205094/datachange-event-tdatasource-linked-to-grid-fires-3-times)

If triggering twice is annoying you, try my workaround for it:

```
var c: integer;  // must be global and reset to 0 when u close your query  

procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
    begin
      if c = 2 then
        begin
          // do your actions
        end
      else
        begin
          inc(c);
        end;
    end;
```

It will eliminate all none necessary triggers,
hope that helps.